# HttpPut Request in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-routing, http-put

I'm fairly new to this Web API stuff and I'm trying to set up simple http requests to a local database on my computer. I have a get request that looks like this:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("")]
[Route("{ID:int}")]
public IQueryable<ListTable> Get(int id = -1)
{
    if(id == -1)
        return db.ListTables;
    else
        return db.ListTables.Where(lt => lt.ID == id);
}
```

This just returns all items in the database or one item relating to the specified ID. Now I'm trying to make a put request where I can add a new item to the database or edit item related to a certain ID. I was trying something like this:

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("{ID:int}")]
[Route("{ID:int}/{TITLE:string}")]
[Route("{ID:int}/{TITLE:string}/{DESCRIPTION:string}")]
public ListTable Put(int id = -1, string title = null, string descr = null)
{
    //if ID == -1 add a new item to the DB
    //else add title and description to the item with the specified ID
}
```

I am a little unsure of how to add a new item to the database and save the changes. I tried something like `db.ListTables.Add(new ListTable())` and `db.SaveChanges()` but those didn't seem to actually save anything because when I called the `Get()` method again the new item wasn't there.

Comment: are you sure method body executes?

Comment: I guess not. Is there an easy way to make sure of that?

Comment: I'm using Chrome's Postman extension to call these methods so I don't see why the body wouldn't execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to new up an instance of the entity to add [`ListTable`] and then add it to your database context (assuming it's `db` based on your `GET` example. Once you add it to the context, then you `.SaveChanges()` - I'm assuming your `ListTable` entity has columns called `Title` and `Description` (change those lines to whatever you have them named):

```
ListTable listTableToAdd = new ListTable() 
{
    Title = title,
    Description = descr
}
db.ListTables.Add(listTableToAdd);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Hmm, this is basically what I did with a little different syntax. I must have something incorrect somewhere else then. I also have a warning that `db.SaveChanges()` is unreachable code... Not even sure how that's possible.

Comment: Actually ignore that first comment. I'm getting a "Validation failed for one or more entities" when I try `db.SaveChanges()`.

Comment: Ignore again! I solved it. One of my required fields was defaulting to null =/ Stupid mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the properties after `new ListTable()`.  Something like `new ListTable() { Title = title, ... }`

Comment: Is this really necessary

Comment: Okay but this doesn't save it to the database still, when I call the get method afterward it's not there and calling `db.SaveChanges()` doesn't seem to do anything. Am I saving it incorrectly?